# Printing a barcode in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

While this example shows the printing of a simple piece of text, i need to be able to print a barcode that i have the font already, that's the simple bit but how does one send it to the printer that is in a network? I have been informed it will need to have an IP address and a port number.

I need to be able to print a barcode 1d or 2d with a price and a description along the bottom. I would normally use visual studio and a Telerik report for that but that's not an option here.

What are my options for printing the example i gave above?

```
private async Task Print()
{
    await Task.Run (() => 
    {
        try
        {
            //As you will see, all depends on your printer commands
            Socket socket = new Socket(YOUR_PRINTSERVER_IP, YOUR_PRINSERVER_TCP_PORT);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter (socket .OutputStream, true);

            //here is the beginning of printing
            pw.Write(0x1B); //Example of command to start a printer
            pw.Print("THIS IS YOUR AWESOME TEXT FOR PRINT");

            pw.Write(0x0C); //here you release the paper
            pw.Write(0x40); //finish printing
            pw.Flush ();
            pw.Close ();
            pw.Dispose();
            socket.Close ();
            socket.Dispose();

        }
        catch(SocketException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketError: "+ex.Message);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What kind of a printer is this? Can you just create a PDF, and then send the PDF to be printed by that printer?

Comment: @Saamer yes Saamer I could do this but its xamrain what tools are avialable for me to create pdf. How does one send a file to be printed rather than just txt.

Comment: since you are using Xamarin, you can use all the native SDK s that are available on Android & iOS that you would be able use if you were coding in Java/Swift. What printer is this and what code are you using to do it through your web app?

Comment: It will be a zerbra label printer

Comment: Is the zebra printer LinkOS compatible? https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/printing-from-apple-ios-or-android-using-a-linkos-compatible-printer.html